# Firebase in app message dont skip activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I want skip message in app on loading screen.

I want firebase in app show message in MainActivity but i dont make this.

Can you help me?

I try use `FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().setMessagesSuppressed(true);`.

But this alway clear all message.

Answer (score 1):

On loading activity(OnCreate) you have to suppressed message by setting flag true and in OnDestroy method set Suppressed method false by following line.

```
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().setMessagesSuppressed(false);
```

So in Main Activity In App Message will render.